# Fade and later, change background with jQuery

Tags: jquery, background-image

I have been searching and it seems that it is not possible to animate background with jQuery.

Then I tried to fade out, change with css and then fade in. I do not understand why it does not follow that order and the css changes first. How can I do that in the order that I mentioned?

(I have a similar effect by putting one div on top of the other and fade the entire div. But for different reasons in the real context, that options have some drawbacks)

```js
$("#boto").click(function() {
  $('#boto').fadeOut(1000)
      .css('background-image', 'url(https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png)')
      .fadeIn(1000);
    });
```

```css
#boto {
 position:absolute;
 top:10px; left:10px;
 width:300px; height:300px;
 
 background-image: url('https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_256.png');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;

 background-color:whiteSmoke;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="boto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the fadeOut to finish, and this should be done by passing a second parameter to the function call, like this:

```js
$("#boto").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png)')
    .fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
#boto {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Badge_256.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: whiteSmoke;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="boto"></div>
```

Comment: Just be careful because if the user doesn't have the image cached, it might bug a little bit because the image will start fading in and loading at the same time.

Comment: Your option works well, thank you!. But still I do not understand why my first shot did not work, what's wrong with it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, but it doesn't work as you think it should do. The fadeOut function runs assyncronously, so your script won't wait for the animation to finish to run the next function call and runs the next step (changing the background) just after it starts fading out. That's why the callback is needed, to run your code only after the animation is finished, and this is done internally.

Comment: Why chaining works with   .slideUp().slideDown(), fadeIn().fadeOut(), delay()... what's different with css background?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#boto').fadeOut(1000).animate({
    backgroundImage: 'url(https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png),
    display: 'block'
}, 1000);
```